# Getting Filtered Selected Rows into Array

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have the following to get selected filtered tabulator rows but I'm not getting any data out of the array, can anyone help please?

```js
document.getElementById("get-selected-rows").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var rows = table.getRows("active");
  var selectedRows = rows.filter(function(row) {

    if (row.isSelected()) {
      var postData = jQuery.map(rows, function(row) {
        return {
          id: row.getData().id,
          FirtName: row.getData().FirtName,
          LastName: row.getData().LastName,
          Age: row.getData().Age,
          City: row.getData().City
        };
      });

      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'save_rows.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(response) {},
        error: function(error) {}
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Your `filter()` callback function doesn't return anything. So `selectedRows` will always be empty.

Comment: Are you sure your PHP script expects the data in JSON format? PHP doesn't parse that automatically into `$_POST`.

Comment: Hi, the PHP expects the array like
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); and then loops through the array, I think my problem lies with the row.getData area of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't make an AJAX call each time through the loop. You should filter the `rows` into the selected rows, then map that to get the array of selected items, and send that in the AJAX call once at the end.

```js
document.getElementById("get-selected-rows").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var rows = table.getRows("active");
  var selectedRows = rows.filter(row => row.isSelected());
  var postData = selectedRows.map(function(row) {
    const data = row.getData();
    return {
      id: data.id,
      FirtName: data.FirtName,
      LastName: data.LastName,
      Age: data.Age,
      City: data.City
    }
  });

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'save_rows.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(response) {},
    error: function(error) {}
  });
});
```